# asp.net web application with c# & vb.net both in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, projects-and-solutions

We currently have a asp.net website with some modules developed in VB.Net & some in C# (not just classes but also individual aspx pages and code behind). We figured we wanted to move to web application model as we need to implement CI with TFS.

The problem :

When we create a C# web application, copy the files from website & say convert to web application it gives `Could not Parse errors` (probably because files are vb.net files)

When we create a VB.NET web application, copy the files & say convert to web application it converts only vb.net pages & on publishing throws error on all c# pages saying `Could not load type`

The asp.net website would work properly with multiple codebehind language support.

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The reason it worked when you had a web site was because the code wasn't compiled until it was needed and then each page would be compiled separately. With a web application the whole thing is compiled into a single dll and you can't mix languages in one dll.

Comment: I realize that the investment has been made, but why are two languages being used? This seems like it would be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: This would be super-useful. We'd love to move to a web application project, but we're generally vb, with quite a few c# pages codebehind. @NerdFury: two reasons: 1. source from the internet such as SqlProfileProvider, Blog, Forum code. 2. Developers wanting to use new language features, copy/paste code from other places (most of our source is vb, but with a fair amount of new c#), and no it's not that bad to maintain - .net developers don't usually struggle reading/writing both vb and c# IME.

Answer (score 3):

Can you break the app into 2 separate web applications that run from the same root directory?  Just put the complied C# dll in the bin with the compiled VB.net dll and place all of the aspx pages wherever they would need to be for your site structure.

I haven't tried this myself, but it should work.  You'll have to create a separate project and reference any data layers, etc. Just move the C# code to the new app and see how that goes.  Not the best solution, but it beats converting from one language to another.

Comment: Just adding some more info around what worked for me: two web app projects (one for vb, one for c#). Make one project your "primary" - create a project reference to your other. Create a post-build event to xcopy all of your .aspx from your secondary project location to your primary location. This should get you into a good place.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the App_Code folder names what contain C# code into [CodeSubDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dwfbb7.aspx) section in your web.config

p.s. this is how it's done in [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com)

Comment: What do I do with the individual aspx pages where some code behinds are vb.net & some are c#?

Comment: wow ... you would have to fix that, you can't just swap languages like that

Comment: It works fine when it was a asp.net web site. Doesnt work in asp.net web application. Any way by which I can make it to work without recoding my entire code to match the language?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with web sites but not web applications. Also note that if you want or need to do this Web applications really don't have any additional level of power that web sites lack. Web applications can have deployment benefits in some environments but visual studio 2010 and 2012 will publish asp.net web sites and web applications both with ease.