# How to use asp.net vb pages in asp.net c# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, integration

We have created our website on ASP.NET with C#. But another developer has created her code on VB.NET. Now we have to integrate her pages and code with our existing application.

Comment: Why not just convert her code to c# instead of trying to make totally different language work together? http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: You should be able to mix-and-match. Try getting her ASPX/VB page and add directly to your C# project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use VB and C# together within the same Web Application project.  What I would recommend is that you convert the VB to C# (or vice-versa) using one of the many automated conversion tools that are available (Telerik has one, for example).  Barring that, your next best bet would be to keep them as separate projects and deploy them together to the same site, if that's an option (for example, if each project will be able to have its own set of URLs).  If that isn't an option, then you will simply have to bite the bullet and convert one language to the other.

Answer (score -1):

For web application project:

### [asp.net web application with c# & vb.net both in codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547308/asp-net-web-application-with-c-sharp-vb-net-both-in-codebehind)

As mentioned by OP in comments, s/he is asking for Web Application projects; so the below is only for website projects:

You don't need to do anything. Just add those `.aspx` and `.aspx.vb` pages in your **website project**. If you are using .NET Framework 2.0 or above, they will compile and the complete website will work.

By the way, if you see, every `.aspx` page contains the `Language` attribute in `@Page` directive which specify the language of the code beside file.

Comment: That only works for web site projects. It won't work with a web application project, where the codebehind all compiles into a DLL. Can't compile C# code plus VB.NET code into the same assembly.

Comment: I did that to a dummy application, it compiled fine, but gave me the following error while opening the site in browser

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication2._Default'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"

Comment: ohhh.... actually from your post "We have created our website on ASP.NET with C#" I thought it is a website project.
Very true that the mixing  will not work in one Web Application project.